# how to setup SSH user with limit permission?

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, tunneling

There are some sites provide SSH accounts only for ssh tunnel. I want to know how to make sure these accounts can only have permission to do tunnel, and how to do limit settings.

And I also notice that github ssh format is ssh://git@github.com:{gituser}/{project}.git , so, I guess github.com use a git account for everyone, but this git account has very limit permission, when user access $gituser/ folder, it do authenticate in another way.

I really want to know how.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402615/how-to-restrict-ssh-users-to-a-predefined-set-of-commands-after-login

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your question is exact duplicate of this: [How to restrict SSH users to a predefined set of commands after login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402615/how-to-restrict-ssh-users-to-a-predefined-set-of-commands-after-login)

[Github blog has a long post in their blog on their architecture](https://github.com/blog/530-how-we-made-github-fast).

But in case you want to set up a git repository for multiple users, then there's project called [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).